# Error getting messages attachements in messages using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am trying to get messages attachements using the Graph API, but are getting this response:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: 8e48235f4d403ddfad3397ade73ed743",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803
   }
}
```

First I get the message in question like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/m_mid.1389103128864:ZZZZZ?access_token=XXXXX
```

where I get this response:

```
...
"attachments": {
  "data": [
     {
        "id": "8e48235f4d403ddfad3397ade73ed743",
        "mime_type": "text/plain",
        "name": "test.txt",
        "size": 33
     }
  ]
}
...
```

Then I try to get the attachment like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/8e48235f4d403ddfad3397ade73ed743?access_token=XXXXX
```

which results in the error response shown above.

How can I get message attachments (using the Graph API, and not FQL)?

Comment: Looks to me as if you can't request attachments which content types different to video or photos via the Graph API. At least I can't retrieve a text file as well via the method you described. How about opening a bug with Facebook?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the input! Yes, looks like something may be off here (getting all kinds of attachements via FQL (where you get an URL for the attachements file) works OK for me).
  I am using the "threads" connection/edge here. It is still "developer only". I am not sure about the actual status of the "threads" connection/edge however?
  As far is I know it is not possible to get attachments at all via the old "inbox" connection/edge?

Comment: Just found this:
"Message attachment not accessible":
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1432682763650844/
"This is not a bug but is in fact by design and is intended for this feature"...